# JavaScript prototyping not working

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I am following an online tutorial and I am at a prototype section.  My `alert` comes back with

```
function() { return this.brand + ' ' + this.model; }
```

Anyone know the reason?

```
function Car(model, brand) {
    this.model = model;
    this.brand = brand;
}

Car.prototype.fullName = function() {
    return this.brand + ' ' + this.model;
}

var s = new Car("G5", "Pontiac");
var full = s.fullName;
alert(full);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

s.fullName is the function itself.  If you wanted to call this function you would have to write s.fullName().

Comment: Yeah, you're calling the property not the function. All function should be called with () = braces.